# Is it possible to rank data after grouping it by observations in R Programming language?

Tags: r, grouping, ranking

I have data on all the US Hospitals regarding certain attributes. A representative sample may look like the one shown below:

```
  Hospital.Name    State       HA      HF      PN    Rank
1    HOSPITAL 1       NY     10.1     7.1     7.7       1
2    HOSPITAL 2       PA     10.4    11.2    11.6       2
3    HOSPITAL 3       SD     10.5     9.9    11.6       3
4    HOSPITAL 4       CA     10.5     8.4     9.7       4
5    HOSPITAL 5       CT     10.6    11.9    11.8       5
6    HOSPITAL 6       PA     10.7     8.3    10.9       6
```

The data shown above is already part processed - arranged and ranked by the attribute "HA" and a column ("Rank") has been added to reflect that.

However, this is not what I need. I am trying to rank this data, grouped by state, for these attributes.

So, the final output would be somewhat like below:

```
  Hospital.Name    State       HA      HF      PN    Rank
1    HOSPITAL 1       AK     12.1     7.1     7.7       1
2    HOSPITAL 2       AK     12.4    11.2    11.6       2
3    HOSPITAL 3       AK     14.5     9.9    11.6       3
4    HOSPITAL 4       AL     11.5     8.4     9.7       1
5    HOSPITAL 5       AL     15.6    11.9    11.8       2
6    HOSPITAL 6       AL     16.7     8.3    10.9       3
```

Please note that value of attribute "HA" for rank 1 of a particular state could be higher or lower than value of attribute HA for rank 1 of another state. Essentially, the ranks for the attribute "HA", within states, are independent.

So, far, I have tried using order and rank functions, nestled, within mutate function. However, both throw up the following error:

> Error: incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1

How can I achieve what I need? Any help / guidance / advice would be highly appreciated.

**Please note that I have data for all the 50 states running into thousands of rows and what is shown in table 1 above is only representative data.

Also, please note that the data in Table 2 above is a sample of the desired output and not the whole output. **

Comment: Can you show the code used for `dplyr`. Also, the input data you showed have a single row for each 'State' except the `PA`.  So, perhaps, `df1 %>% group_by(State) %>% mutate(Rank=rank(HA))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @akrun. So far, I have used Data %>% group_by(State) %>% mutate(Rank = rank(Data$HA) and Data %>% group_by( State) %>% mutate(Rank=order(Data$HA).

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: No, these commands throw up the error specified above and that's why I posted the question here.

Comment: Based on the data you posted, I am not getting any error

Comment: You were using the whole column `rank(Data$HA)` inside each group, (which should result in error as the sizes are not the same)  which is not the code I used i.e. `rank(HA)`

Comment: I get the same error by `df1 %>% group_by(State) %>% mutate(Rank=rank(df1$HA))#
Error: incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1`

Comment: I will change my code. Just to clarify, when the code is run with rank(HA), for the input data in first table in my query, is the output restricted to those five states. I ask because the second table is the desired output and is only representative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution using `dplyr`. You can group by the State and then do the ranking:

```
dt <- data.table(Hospital.Name = "Hospital", 
           State = rep(c("AK", "AL"), each = 2), 
           HA = c(10,12,11,14)) 

dt %>% 
  group_by(State) %>%
  mutate(Rank = rank(HA))
```

output:

```
  Hospital.Name State HA Rank
1      Hospital    AK 10    1
2      Hospital    AK 12    2
3      Hospital    AL 11    1
4      Hospital    AL 14    2
```

One more word on the confusion that came up:

`rank(dt$HA)` gives a vector (here size 4) whereas `rank(HA)` gives a scalar which represents the current rank of the current row within the column HA (also on the group basis if specified).

Comment: This is almost similar to the code I posted in the comments but the OP said that it is giving error

Comment: Oops, didnt see that. Does this code work for you OP?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear in the question I posted. I have data on all the 50 US states. So, I need to group the data by all the states and then rank them within the states. The code suggested above focuses on the desired output, restricted to the two states I showed above.... I am not sure if this is what I needed.

Comment: @akrun Do you want to post the answer? You suggested it before I did.

Comment: No, it's okay.  I commented to your answer because the OP mentioned it is giving errors (without copy/pasting the same code).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `ave()` (note: I randomized the row order to demonstrate that it does not depend on any particular row order in the input):

```
set.seed(317);
df <- data.frame(Hospital.Name=c('HOSPITAL 1','HOSPITAL 2','HOSPITAL 3','HOSPITAL 4','HOSPITAL 5','HOSPITAL 6'), State=c('AK','AK','AK','AL','AL','AL'), HA=c(12.1,12.4,14.5,11.5,15.6,16.7), HF=c(7.1,11.2,9.9,8.4,11.9,8.3), PN=c(7.7,11.6,11.6,9.7,11.8,10.9) )[sample(6),];
df$Rank <- ave(df$HA,df$State,FUN=function(x) match(1:length(x),order(x)));
df;
##   Hospital.Name State   HA   HF   PN Rank
## 3    HOSPITAL 3    AK 14.5  9.9 11.6    3
## 1    HOSPITAL 1    AK 12.1  7.1  7.7    1
## 6    HOSPITAL 6    AL 16.7  8.3 10.9    3
## 4    HOSPITAL 4    AL 11.5  8.4  9.7    1
## 2    HOSPITAL 2    AK 12.4 11.2 11.6    2
## 5    HOSPITAL 5    AL 15.6 11.9 11.8    2
```

Comment: Need a clarification - will the proposed solution require the column data points to be hard coded as shown or can just the columns be referred? .. I have a dataset running into few thousand rows, loaded into a .csv file (with generous amounts of NAs).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "column data points"? Nothing is hard-coded in my solution except for the column names of the ranked column (`df$HA`) and the group column (`df$State`). If you prefer to use column indexes rather than column names, that can certainly be done instead, provided that you know which indexes to use, of course (these would be `df[[3]]` and `df[[2]]`, respectively, for your example data.frame).